# Java polymorphism arrays sub-types to each other

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism, subtype

I know that Java is static language, and there is dynamic check when it comes to arrays :
but I can't understand why this happen, can someone explain to me this example in both cases when : A[] is sub-type to B[], or B[] is sub-type to A[] ? which will fail and why ?

```
f(A[] as) {
  as[0] = new A(); // **?!**
}

B[] bs = new B[10];
f(bs); // **?!**
B b = bs[0]; // **?!**
```

Comment: Try it by using a compiler.

Comment: What is the output you get and what is the output you expect?

Comment: "but I can't understand why this happen"... What happens?

Comment: I can use a compiler , but I want to understand why ? to learn more about the dynamic aspects of the language .

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in Java is [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

Which means if `B` is a subtype of `A` then `B[]` is also a subtype of `A[]`. So, you can pass a `B[]` where `A[]` is expected just like you can pass a `B` where an `A` is expected.

But if you go the opposite way then you would need an explicit cast like -

```
 B b = (B) new A(); //bypasses the compiler but fails at runtime
 B[] bs = (B[]) new A[1]; //also bypasses the compiler but fails at runtime
```